# Shell script to check hadoop client

Tags: shell, hadoop, cloudera, hortonworks-data-platform, cloudera-cdh

I want to write a simple shell script which should check if there is a Hadoop Client installed, and what kind (CDH, HDP or generic). Later that script must also print the appropriate version. Can anyone provide me suggestion for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your PATH is correct and you're using standard installations you only need to run hadoop version.

```
if /usr/bin/which hadoop; then
  if [ -d /usr/hdp ]; then
    echo "HDP"
  elif hadoop version | grep cdh > /dev/null; then
    echo "CDH"
  else
    echo "generic"
  fi
else
  echo "no hadoop found"
fi
```

Comment: but this will not return me specific versions of CDH /HDP or generic installed

Comment: hadoop version tells the version of hadoop.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the other answer to be a bit more robust by cleaning up the output and adding support for the 3 main hadoop platforms (Hortonworks Data Platform, IBM Open Platform, and Cloudera Data Hub) we get the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

CDH_HOME=/opt/cloudera/parcels
HDP_HOME=/usr/hdp
IOP_HOME=/usr/iop

if /usr/bin/which hadoop > /dev/null 2>&1; then
  if [ -d $HDP_HOME ]; then
    platform="HDP"
    version=`hdp-select status hadoop-client | awk -F "-" '{print $3}'`
  elif [ -d $IOP_HOME ]; then
    platform="IOP"
    version=`iop-select status hadoop-client | awk -F "-" '{print $3}'`
  elif [ -d $CDH_HOME ]; then
    platform="CDH"
    version=`readlink $CDH_HOME/CDH`
  else
    platform="Other"
    version="Unknown"
  fi
  echo "Platform: $platform"
  echo "Version: $version"
else
  echo "No hadoop found"
fi
```

Note: The platform select utility (ie. hdp-select) can give you information about all the installed services on the given node. Status will be given as `None` when not installed.